# salesforce.com Formula : How to check if the Record is new

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have to calculate the agreement value for my new record .Assuming that agreement value is ending_days - begining_days. I have put this formula in my object.

IF(Beginning_*c <> Ending*_c,Ending_*c-Beginning*_c,0).

I have two questions related to this

1: What is the agreement value ?, Am i correct in assuming what i have assumed or does it some specific other meaning?

2: I have to create an agreement value for new records only. So, should i take care of this fact in my IF condition For example : should my IF code look something like this

IF (AND(//somehow check if the record is new,Beginning_*c <> Ending*_c),Ending_*c-Beginning*_c,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if `Beginning__c == Ending__c` then `Ending__c-Beginning__c` is already 0 so your formula does not need IF at all.

Second, formula is evaluated every time its referenced in SOQL, if you want a once-off calculation you should use `before insert` trigger or a workflow and store result in regular field.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on the second point. i am new to databases and apex coding too. Thanks !

Comment: See here -> http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_triggers.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Answer (score 1):

To answer part 2 of your question. Use the function ISNEW() in you formula.
So your complete formula would be:

```
IF (AND(ISNEW(),Beginning_c <> Ending_c),Ending_c-Beginning_c,0)
```